# Php generate multiple array() without duplicate value and match with other array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 data.

`$dataA = 01,05,07;`

`$dataB = 01,07;`

Now, I would like to explode the $dataA and combine back with only 2 string. like below:

```
$explode = explode(',',$dataA);
/*combine back get the max combination without duplicate string, example for the $dataA.
My suspect is: first array (01,05), second array(05,07), third array(07,01), I don't need (05,01) since first array have both value.
*/
```

After that, if the combination array value match with the `$dataB` (no matter which the value position is), then do something like:

```
$array[0] = '01,05';
$array[1] = '05,07';
$array[2] = '07,01'; 
//since $array[2] value = $dataB (no need to check specific position); so I would like to do as below

if(in_array(third array,$dataB)){ //use in_array or?
  //do something
}
```

Is it any `array` function can done this?

Comment: There is no a single function to do that, but you can combine several functions from [the list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) to achieve this.

Comment: Do you simply need to test whether two numbers from `01,07` present in `01,05,07`?